# How to calculate the worst case complexity for the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, complexity-theory

```
def functionX(L):
     """ L is a non-empty list of length len(L) = n. """
     i= 1
     while i< len(L) -1:
         j = i-1
         while j <= i+ 1:
             L[j] = L[j] + L[i]
             j = j + 1
         i= i+ 1
```

For j loop why do we have 3 iterations each with 3 steps instead of i iterations? I have hard time figuring it out.

Comment: 3 iterations in the inner loop, because you set `j` to `i-1` and loop until it is `i+1`. The worst-case (and average case and every case) complexity is O(n).

Comment: @en_Knight because `j` is not independent from `i`

Comment: @Ian right. Maybe I misunderstood your previous comment, I thought you were suggesting it was O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

Is it clearer with for loops than while loops?

```
def functionY(L):
    N = len(L)
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        for j in range(i-1,i+2):
            L[j] = L[j] + L[i]
```

How about pseudo-code?

```
for i in range(N): # drop the -1s on both ends; O(n-2) = O(n)
    for j in range(3): # (i-1) to (i+2) covers 3 elements
        do something
```

This makes it pretty clear that Tony's answer is correct, we're in the class O(n). Specifically, the line `L[j] = L[j] + L[i]` will be accessed `3n-6` times. This is in the complexity class `O(3n) = O(n)`. If you're looking at array accesses as your atomic operation, then we have `O(3*(3n-6)) = O(n)`, still. The complexity class would not change if the line read `L[j] += L[i]`, though the total number of array accesses would go down.

Answer (score 1):

You have `n` iterations of the outer loop and in every outer-loop-iteration, `3` iterations of the inner loop, because for given `i`, variable `j` has a value of `i - 1`, `i` and `i + 1`. Therefore the complexity equals `O(3 * n) = O(n)`.